# @TestPropertySource and UTF-8 support in properties files

Tags: java, spring, encoding, integration-testing, spring-test

I'm working on integration tests for my Spring application and I want to be able to read properties files in test class using UTF-8 encoding.

Now if I want to have 'ä' character in my properties I need to put it as an U\00E4 in my properties files because by default properties files are read with ISO-8859-1.

How can I configure my test application context to read properties files in UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 2):

***1. Generate the .properties from a UTF-8 file:***
In the build infra structure, like maven, one can copy the .properties files using a filter that u-escapes the UTF-8 sources to ISO-8859-1 in the build directory: converting `ĉ` to `\u0109`.

Its advantage is that no non-standard features are used, and ResourceBundle may be used.

***2. A good properties editor:***
The disadvantage of the prior solution is that no longer a property editor can be used (different languages side-by-side), is minor, as a good property editor shows the Unicode characters and u-escapes in the background. So when working with a **properties editor** one need do nothing and leave the file in ISO-8859-1.

***3. Not ResourceBundle but Properties:***
However the class **Properties** can load UTF-8. Then one should not use ResourceBundle.
In Spring that means, do not use `ResourceBundleMessageSource`, but `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value=".../test/classes/..."/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

(By the way: `ä` or `\u00E4` is an ISO-8859-1 character and would need no u-escaping, when the editor is set to ISO-8859-1. So try tests with Greek, Cyrillic or such.)